# mysql multiple keyword search in any order

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, keyword

I have a simple MySQL database keyword search that is functional. However results for the search are not being returned if the keywords are not in the same order as entered in the database. For example searching for "dog cat lion" will return a result, but searching for "dog lion cat" will return no results.
Any help on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Part Search</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
mysql_select_db("wesco");

$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchterm']));

$find_parts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%$search%'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_parts))
{
$name = $row['name'];
echo "$name<br />";

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
$searchArray = explode(" ", $_POST['searchterm']);
$query = "";
foreach($searchArray as $val) {
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($val));
    if (!empty($query)) {
        $query = $query . " OR "; // or AND, depends on what you want
    }

    $query = $query . "`keywords` LIKE '%$search%'";
}

if (!empty($query)) {
    $find_parts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE $query");
}
```

Also, you should stop using the `mysql_*` functions and start using the object oriented implementation of mysqli.

Comment: Thank you for your solution however I cannot seem to get this code to return any results at all now...

Comment: got it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your Query.
if you have an auto_incremented Id you could go:

```
$find_parts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY row_id asc");
```

you can order by Name or really anything:

```
$find_parts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name asc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. use the build in mysql search functionality.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

this is probably the better solution.

2. if you want to continue to use LIKE, then split the words as follows.

   select *
   from parts
   where 
   (
   keywords LIKE '%$word1%'
   AND
   keywords LIKE '%$word2%'
   AND
   keywords LIKE '%$word3%'
   )

Comment: with solution #2 would I need to insert '%$word#%' for every search element? What if I want an unlimited number of keywords to be able to be used?

Comment: you'd need to dynamically generate an sql statement. solution 1 seems cleaner to me if you can change your DB.